# DVTSourceControlGitXPCClient crash on Xcode 14

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, git, macos

Since a few days ago, I've been experiencing a repetitive crash on **Xcode** every 3-8 minutes.

The only tangible thing I can find in the crash logs is that it always shows:

> Crashed Thread: Dispatch queue: DVTSourceControlGitXPCClient :: Proxy Completion Queue

It seems to be Source Control related, but I wonder how?

I will add everything related to my current project in case it is relevant:

- `Xcode 14.2 (14C18)`
- Using Source Control with GitHub
- Swift targets iOS and macOS
- SPM

It seems like some folks are experiencing a similar issue, as seen on the [Developer Forums](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/717080)

Any leads as to why or how to solve it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After some struggling I decided to check how was **git** doing, directly from the **Terminal**.

It turns out there were some things that didn't make sense, specifically a file I deleted from my project but then added again, was showing as `modified`, even though I had already committed all changes for that file a few days ago; but I had done it directly from **Xcode** Source Control.

From the **Terminal**, I staged all changes and committed them. Since then Xcode hasn't crashed for a few hours yet.

My limited understanding of the problem points out that Xcode had issues staging those changes I made a few days ago, and since then the repository has not been in a "healthy state"; Xcode tries somehow to understand the state of the repository but after a while, it just crashes.

Common scenarios where this could have happened:

- A file was deleted
- A file was renamed, specially with case-sensitive renames, for example from `MyViewcontroller.swift` to `MyViewController.swift`

The **solution** for me was to just put it back in a "healthy state", aka **make a commit directly from the Terminal**.

## Example

From the Terminal

```bash
# navigate to the directory of your repository
$ cd /someFolder/myProjectApp

$ git status
# check that you get "nothing to commit"
# or if there are changes they should make sense

# if some changes do not make sense
# try staging and committing everything
# example:
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "Cleaning state"
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to prevent the crash by unchecking the `Fetch and refresh server status automatically` in Xcode > Preferences > Source Control > General. (Not a game-stopper for me since I'm the only one using the remote server, and I do all of my committing and other git operations in a third-party GUI app).

I also tend to perpetually have locally modified files that I never commit, so the other answer wasn't an option for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to disable various options under the `Source Control`, they all crash abruptly.

The only effective way is to uncheck the "Enable Source Control" option:

[image]

This is inconvenient, but I can't work with a crashing Xcode
¯_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem where Xcode kept crashing with this error, and it began appearing after I interactively staged individual lines/hunks. I had several edits in a particular file and I didn't want to commit all the changes but only wanted to commit certain lines/hunks. I solved this Xcode crash issue by reverting the "line" commits and just committing the entire file.

Xcode bug if you ask me.