# Reappearing Editor placeholder in source file in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I keep getting the "Editor placeholder in source file" error in my project. Whenever I click on the error, it takes me to the file and the error instantaneously disappears, only to reappear later.

Here's the code:

```swift
import SwiftUI

@main
struct FooodApp: App {
    @StateObject var storage = Storage()
    @StateObject var anotherStorage = AnotherStorage()
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environmentObject(storage)
                .environmentObject(anotherStorage)
                .task {
                    do {
                        try await storage.load()
                    } catch {
                        fatalError(error.localizedDescription)
                    }
                }
                .task {
                    do {
                        try await anotherStorage.load()
                    } catch {
                        fatalError(error.localizedDescription)
                    }
                }
                
        }
    }
}
```

This is the entirety of the file that Xcode complains about. Here's what I tried:

- Cutting out the entire code from the file and pasting it back
- Rewriting the code in the file from scratch
- Cmd + Shift + B
- Product > Clean Build Folder...
- Closing the project
- Closing Xcode

My Storage is an `ObservableObject` class with one `@Published` initialized property.

Is there something obvious that I'm missing?

---

### Edit 1

As requested, I'm providing the ContentView(). The original struct has also changed slightly since (see above).

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var storage: Storage
    @EnvironmentObject var anotherStorage: AnotherStorage
    
    @State private var selectedTab: Tab = .anotherView
    
    enum Tab {
        case someView
        case anotherView
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $selectedTab) {
            SomeView() {
                Task {
                    do {
                        try await storage.save(items: storage.items)
                    } catch {
                        fatalError(error.localizedDescription)
                    }
                }
            }
            .tabItem {
                Label("View", systemImage: "bookmark.fill")
            }
            .tag(Tab.someView)
            
            AnotherView {
                Task {
                    do {
                        try await anotherStorage.save(item: anotherStorage.item)
                    } catch {
                        fatalError(error.localizedDescription)
                    }
                }
            }
            .tabItem {
                Label("Another", systemImage: "person.fill")
            }
            .tag(Tab.anotherView)
        }
        .onAppear {
            let appearance = UITabBarAppearance()
            appearance.backgroundEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: .systemUltraThinMaterial)
            UITabBar.appearance().standardAppearance = appearance
            UITabBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
            .environmentObject(Storage())
            .environmentObject(AnotherStorage())
    }
}
```

---

### Edit 2

I had another issue in my project, caused by Source Control. Xcode apparently didn't push all changes to the remote and would crash every few minutes, even when idle. Resolving the issue (as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75185203/12853922)) seems to have dealt with this error as well.

The two issues are somewhat related — the IDE might have seen something that was no longer there. Normally, the editor placeholder error goes away after reopening the project or Xcode (or fixing code). In my case, I had to commit and push to the remote changes that Xcode overlooked.

Comment: show the code for `ContentView()`.

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine I didn't have the error appear before adding TabView and onAppear. The code in onAppear was added to bring back the old iOS semi-transparent TabView. I suppose there are plenty of ways to improve my code in the two files. If there's anything especially wrong with it, I'd appreciate any input.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to use `SomeView()` and `AnotherView()` as if they were functions
with some closure, but they are not functions.

Try this structure in your `TabView`,

```
 SomeView()
     .onAppear {
         Task {
             do {
                 try await storage.save(items: storage.items)
             } catch {
                 fatalError(error.localizedDescription)
             }
         }
     }
```

or

```
SomeView()
    .task {
        do {
            try await storage.save(items: storage.items)
        } catch {
            fatalError(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
```

similarly for `AnotherView()`

Comment: Both of these have `let saveAction: ()->Void` properties with empty actions, which are passed from the `ContentView`. I was following [this tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/app-dev-training/persisting-data) on data persistence. I had another issue with Source Control. After resolving it, the editor placeholder error hasn't occurred (so far). Either way, thanks for your help!